# Why are payments for a game sometimes called "donations"?

Tags: legal, monetization, terminology

Why are money payments (by SMS, or VISA) sometimes called "donations", and not "payments" or "purchases"? Is it a legal part of monetization (some details will be appreciated in this case), or just a habit (who was the first)?

Comment: Any reasons of downvotes? I'll be pleased

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think it might be because your question is asked from the perspective of a player, not a game developer. This does make it only marginally constructive for the scope of this website. I was thinking about suggesting a migration to gaming.stackexchange.com, but I wouldn't do that without being absolutely sure that it's on-topic there.

Comment: -1 for generalizing without any examples. IMHO initial statement needs more backup to have a subsequent question base on it.

Comment: @KromStern understood. I'll try to be concrete next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I've encountered the term "Donation" for "Cash shop payment" only among amateurs who host smaller games in their free-time (often half-legal private servers which emulate the server software of commercial MMORPGs). Anyone who is an actual professional uses the term "payment" and is proud of it.

Many amateur MMORPGs want to keep up the image of a non-profit volunteer initiative without commercial interest. They hope that by not giving the appearance of a profit-oriented business, they can stay under the radar of both the IRS (to avoid bookkeeping duties) and also IP holders, because often the software and assets they use might not be *quite* legal to use for them.

This strategy is usually flawed. Some server operators make much more money through "donations" than is required to cover their fix-cost and generate an income for them. And even when they wouldn't - it would likely not protect them from any legal issues whatsoever.

Another context where the term "Donation" sometimes pops up is during crowdfunding. While supporting a crowdfunded project often feels like a donation you pay because you really want to see the project to become reality, it actually isn't. A true donation is when your expect nothing in return. But very few crowdfunding initiatives do not reward their backers in some way. Backers usually receive a copy of the finished game, merchandise or other rewards for their money. So when people contribute money to a crowdfunding, it is basically a very early preorder of the planned product.

Comment: My guesses confirmed, thanks! Yes, I remember several "donators" from Moscow who spent ~ 5000-6000$ for their characters (lineage II, "half-legal" RU server). There was some ways to do it in less amounts of money (buy some items from players with good reputation, buy special software from top clans to use bots), but they've decided to be honest) One of them was banned some time later :D he didn't stopped playing)